# how to create a flexible number of posts using prisma

Tags: prisma

This might not be possible but is there a way to create an flexible amount of posts in prisma. For example, I have a user and I would like them to create be able to create any amount of posts at once, so it would be one post or three posts. Is this possible using Prisma?

Here is the query I'm using:

```
const user = await prisma.user.update({
  where: {
    id: 9,
  },
  data: {
    posts: {
// This is where I would like to make the amount of posts being created on the frontend flexible
      createMany: {
        data: [{ title: 'My first post' }, { title: 'My second post' }],
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go an example how to do that:

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client')
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

const saveData = async () => {
  const user = await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      name: 'John Doe',
      posts: {
        createMany: {
          data: [
            {
              title: 'First Post',
            },
          ],
        }
      }
    },
    include: {
      posts: true
    }
  })

  console.log(JSON.stringify(user, null, 2));

  await prisma.user.update({
    where: {
      id: user.id
    },
    data: {
      posts: {
        createMany: {
          data: [
            {
              title: 'Second Post',
            },
            {
              title: 'Third Post',
            }
          ],
        }
      }
    }
  })

  console.log(JSON.stringify(await prisma.user.findMany({ include: {posts: true} }), null, 2));
}

saveData()
```

And here you go the result

[image]

Comment: Thanks luisbar, please can you explain to me whats going on here? From what I can see the SaveData function is creating a post, then your'e updating the user and adding a second and third post. Is that correct? What I am after is a user that is already created, being able to add an undetermined amount of posts from the front end. I want it to be flexible, so the prisma.update function can handle any number of posts sent to it.

Comment: Yes it is correct, and I understood that is what you want or misunderstood you?, and you can add many post as you want using the update method